# jquery: get and set image, repeat from background css

Tags: jquery, background

For some reason, I need to not allow user get and set background-image and background-repeat,
then I use background instead.

How to get and set image, repeat and position from background css?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

Background image

Getting:

```
$('selector').css('background-image');
$('selector').css('background-repeat');
$('selector').css('background-position');
```

Seting:

```
$('selector').css({
    backgroundImage: 'url(' + imageUrl + ')'
    ,backgroundRepeat: 'repeat-x'
    ,backgroundPosition: '10px 10px'
});;
```

Comment: I think you don't understand my question, however thank for you reply.

Comment: Ok, tell me more about your problem and I could help you. Thanks

Comment: How to extract background color, image, repeat, attachment, position from => background: rgb(255,255,0) url('http://xxx.com/abc.jpg') repeat scroll right 0px;. NOT from => background-color, background-image, background-repeat, etc Thank You.

Comment: You can set a style like:
background: rgb(255,255,0) url('xxx.com/abc.jpg';) repeat scroll right 0px;
And get it separately with:
jQuery.css('background-image');
jQuery.css('background-color');
jQuery.css('background-repeat');
jQuery.css('background-position'); But I'll post a alternative answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can get entire style attribute and parse it, because jquery get these values only separately.

```
// All style attribute value
var strStyle = $('selector').attr('style');
// Find 'background' and store until the end.
strStyle = strStyle.substring(strStyle.indexOf('background:')+11);
// Strip the next rules
var strBackground = strStyle.split(';')[0];
```

You can do it more briefly

```
var strStyle = $('selector').attr('style');
var strBackground = strStyle.substring(strStyle.indexOf('background:')+11).split(';')[0];
```

And now I could help?